# How to change the value of an element with array_walk?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How can I change the **value** of an element with array_walk?

For instance, this is my array,

```
$items = array(
    0 => array( 
        "id" => "1",
        "title" => "parent 1",
       "children" => array()
        ),

    1 => array( 
        "id" => "2",
        "title" => "parent 2",
        "children" => array (
           0 => array( 
            "id" => "4",
            "title" => "children 1"
            ),
           1 => array( 
            "id" => "5",
            "title" => "children 2"
            ) 
        ),
   )
);
```

And I can change it with this below,

```
function myfunction(&$item,$key)
{
    if($item['id'] === '1')
    {
        $item['title'] = 'hello world en';
    }   
}


array_walk($items,"myfunction");

print_r($items);
```

But I have a nested children and I want to change the value in that too, and I will get error if I do this,

```
function myfunction(&$item,$key)
{
    if($item['id'] === '1')
    {
        $item['title'] = 'hello world en';
    }

    if($item['id'] === '4')
    {
        $item['title'] = 'hello world en';
    }


    foreach($item as $key => $value)
    {

        if(is_array($value))
        {
            myfunction($value,$key);
        }
    }

}
```

error,

> Notice: Undefined index: id in ...index.php on line xx

Any idea what should I do if there is a nested children in an array?

Comment: In first place you should not have `$arr['hardcodedKeyName']` before any check is done. You cannot be sure this key is present or not. You should recursively get through the last depth of array searching for `id` and change if present, then go to the beginning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may achieve that with recursive call of your callback function. I've implemented sample with closure, like:

```
//replacement array:
$replace = [
  '1' => 'foo',
  '2' => 'bar',
  '5' => 'baz'
];

array_walk($items, $f=function(&$value, $key) use (&$f, $replace)
{
   if(isset($replace[$value['id']]))
   {
      $value['title'] = $replace[$value['id']];
   }
   if(isset($value['children']))
   {
      //the loop which is failing in question:
      foreach($value['children'] as $k=>&$child)
      {
         $f($child, $k);
      }
      //Proper usage would be - to take advantage of $f
      //array_walk($value['children'], $f);
   }
});
```

As you can see - all that you need is to pass value by reference and iterate it inside callback as a reference for `foreach` too.

Comment: Interesting recursive solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a line such as `if (!isSet($item['id'])) var_dump($item);` you will see why you get the undefined index.

Although I am not sure why you're doing this (how are you taking advantage of `array_walk()`?), to solve this, you could use something like the following:

```
function myfunction(&$item,$key)
{
    if ($item['id'] === '1')
    {
        $item['title'] = 'hello world en';
    }

    if ($item['id'] === '4')
    {
        $item['title'] = 'hello world en';
    }


    if (isSet($item['children']) && is_array($item['children']))
        array_walk($item['children'], __FUNCTION__);
}
```

Which will work with the example given.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($item as $key => $value)
{

    if(is_array($value))
    {
        myfunction($value,$key);
    }
}
```

You walk through every key in your $item (id, title, children). But I guess what you want is moving through every ELEMENT of $value['children'] (value['children'][0], value['children'][1]), right? So it might be something like this:

```
if(is_array($value)){
   foreach($item['children'] as $key => $value){
      myfunction($value,$key);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're passing in your whole array of children, not each individual item of children. [See this eval](https://eval.in/172627) for how it should look. And here's the code:

```
<?php
$items = array(
    0 => array( 
        "id" => "1",
        "title" => "parent 1",
        "children" => array()
    ),

    1 => array( 
        "id" => "2",
        "title" => "parent 2",
        "children" => array (
           0 => array( 
            "id" => "4",
            "title" => "children 1"
            ),
           1 => array( 
            "id" => "5",
            "title" => "children 2"
            ) 
        ),
   )
);

function myfunction(&$item) {
  if($item['id'] == '1' || $item['id'] == '4') {
    $item['title'] = 'hello world en';
  }
  if( ! empty($item['children'])) {
    array_walk($item['children'], "myfunction");
  }
}

array_walk($items, "myfunction");

var_dump($items);
```

Answer (score -1):

In the code you posted you are not passing the reference through `foreach`.
This should work with the code you posted.

```
foreach($item as $key => &$value)
{
    if(is_array($value)) {
        myfunction($value,$key);
    }
}
```

And to you don't see the undefined index, just check if that is setted before comparing the values:

```
if(isset($item['id'])){
    if($item['id'] === '1'){
      ...
    }
}
```

[Online example](http://ideone.com/jAu5K7)

Comment: Not sure it's relevant

Comment: @RoyalBg well, I just tested online and worked. Ill update to add the link

Comment: The errors for undefined indices are still present, you saw? `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /home/v5qmCF/prog.php on line 28
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /home/v5qmCF/prog.php on line 33
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /home/v5qmCF/prog.php on line 28
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /home/v5qmCF/prog.php on line 33`

Comment: @RoyalBg Yes, of course there are better ways of doing this, and I didn't correct all errors, etc. Im just saying why his code is not updating the values in deep levels.

Comment: A part of the main question was about the undefined index error